# I am trying to join tables where a user record does not exist in one of the tables

Tags: mysql, apache-spark-sql

I have a rewards program with a grants and a purchases table. I am attempting to create a report that displays a users balance. If the user has not made a purchase, however, the balance report does not contain their record. The report only contains users who have earned grants AND made at least one purchase.

The third table being used is our user records table to pull in the user record.

Is there a way to treat no record in the purchases table as a '0' balance?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not have an entry for every user with a 0 balance? That is the reason this wont work. You are asking the database to join/display something that does not exist.

Without the join, you can display no records as 0 but you won't be able to create a join to nothing so I suggest you add an entry for each user (when the users account is created) in the purchases tablet with a 0 balance.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchases WHERE purchase_user_id = user_id) > 0
     THEN balance_value
     ELSE 0
 END as balance
```

EDIT: Going by the query that you added, I think you can just `COALESCE` the amount to 0 before doing the `SUM()`. This should prevent returning a NULL value if there are no records in the purchases table.

```
SELECT ce.platform_id,
       SUM(COALESCE(p.amount, 0))
FROM current_eligibility ce
LEFT JOIN purchases p ON p.platformId = ce.platform_id
WHERE p.currency = 'X123' AND
      ce.platform_id = 'X2334'
GROUP BY ce.platform_id
```

Comment: okay great this should work... im trying to work it into my existing query, if you could assist that'd be awesome:

`select
  ce.platform_id,
  sum(p.amount)
from 
  current_eligibility ce
  left join purchases p on p.platformId = ce.platform_id
 
where
  p.currency = 'c1ae0da9-4812-4025-9ee7-53cda7eb600b' and
  ce.platform_id = 'bca568ec2ed1bc738a70cf022520f3ed9b7c8d6a'

group by 
  ce.platform_id`

Comment: Updated answer to add query.

Comment: I am still not returning anything. should bringing in the grants table to ensure the user is on there, and then somehow fill the purchases amount column as 0 work? heres what that would look like

    SELECT ce.platform_id,
       SUM(COALESCE(p.amount, 0))
    FROM purchases p
    LEFT JOIN current_eligibility ce ON p.platformId = ce.platform_id
    LEFT JOIN grants g ON g.platformId = ce.platform_id
    WHERE p.currency = 'X1234' AND
      ce.platform_id = 'X2334'
    GROUP BY ce.platform_id

Comment: though this seems to be multiplying sum of grants column by the sum of purchases

Comment: You would need to update your GROUP BY if you joined to another table or you will more than likely be summing duplicated rows